# After upgrading Ubuntu from 18.04 to 20.04, `systemctl suspend` no longer works

Tags: 20.04, suspend

I have Ubuntu 20.04 installed on a desktop Dell machine. I access it through XRDP and SSH for routine use.

It has been hugely convenient with Ubuntu 18.04 to suspend the system using the `systemctl suspend` command and then resume the next day using a magic packet wake-on-LAN. A few seconds and I am back where I left off.

After the upgrade to Ubuntu 20.04, `systemctl suspend` would no longer function properly; the system tries to stop, but a second or two later, it resumes on its own. I suspect a process is preventing suspend:

```
$ sudo systemd-inhibit --list --mode=block
WHO UID USER PID  COMM           WHAT                                                    
gdm 125 gdm  1406 gsd-media-keys handle-power-key:handle-suspend-key:handle-hibernate-key>
```

After a bit of research, I tried:

```
echo mem | sudo tee /sys/power/state
```

to override the inhibit, which did stop the machine (although the power button remained lit instead of blinking like it did before). However, unfortunately, the IP address was changed on resume, creating a big mess. I use DHCP on my ISP's modem/router. I can't seem to fix the IP address and keep it static.

Is there some way to get `systemctl suspend` to work properly? A possible workaround is to find a way to keep the IP address from changing (manually setting the IP address statically didn't work).